Finding a function that is a pivotal quantity of the MLE
I'm confused on how to find a function $g_{(1)}$ of the MLE that is a pivotal quantity. I've never seen such notation for a function before. Here is the problem statement:
Let $Y_1$,$Y_2$,...,$Y_n$ be a random sample from a population with density function
$f(y|\theta)=\frac{2\theta^2}{y^3}$, where $\theta < y < \infty$ (and 0 otherwise).
We know that $Y_{(1)} = min(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$ is sufficient for $\theta$, and that $\hat{\theta}$ = $Y_{(1)}$ is a MLE for $\theta$. I am asked to Find a function
$g_{(1)}$ of the MLE above that is a pivotal quantity, whereas it is represented as:
$g_{(1)} =$ blank, $y > \theta$
I am also asked to find a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$.
I say that the pivotal quantity is $\frac{Y_{(1)}}{\theta}$, however I'm not sure where to find the PDF of $\frac{Y_{(1)}}{\theta}$ in order to find $g_{(1)}$.

This symbol means order statistic

It is true that $T=\frac{Y_{(1)}}{\theta}$ is a pivotal quantity. We must show that the distribution of $T$ does not depend on $\theta$. To that end note that
$$
P(Y_{(1)}>y) = P(Y_{1}>y)^n=\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{y^2}\right)^n.
$$
where we have used the fact that the $Y_i$ are i.i.d. Hence
$$
P(T>y) = P(Y_{(1)}>\theta y)^n=\left(1-\frac{1}{y^2}\right)^n
$$
as desired.
